# Regex: find word between slash and matching keyword in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

eg:

```
http://www.domain.com/junk/target/keyword/junk
```

I'm trying to pull the word 'target' from the above url.
So far I have the following expression:

```
(?=\/).*?(?=\/keyword\/)
```

however this pulls everything from the first slash ('//www.domain.com/junk/target')

Comment: The reason your regex failed is that `\/` will match the first `/` in the string, and `.*?` will match any 0+ chars up to the `/keyword/`, thus including any `/` it finds on its way. A negated character class `[^/]` is the easiest fix in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
%r{/([^/]+)/keyword/}
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/tIYCkOeWOZ) (note that if `keyword` may appear at the end of the string, you will need to add an alternation at the end - `%r{/([^/]+)/keyword(?:/|\z)}`).

The value you need is inside Group 1.

[Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/UhkPGv):

```
lnk[%r{/([^/]+)/keyword/}, 1]
```

**Pattern description**:

- `/`  - a slash
- `([^/]+)`  - Capturing group 1 matching one or more chars other than `/`
- `/keyword/` - a literal `/keyword/` substring.

Comment: You can use the %r literal to make it slightly more readable. %r{/([^/]+)/keyword/}

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negated character class in combination with the positive lookahead:

```
[^\/]+(?=\/keyword)
```

Explanation:

- `[^\/]+` - Negated character set to match one or more `/` characters
- `(?=\/keyword)` - Positive lookahead to match the following `/keyword` string.

Of course you could also just use a capturing group:

```
\/([^\/]+)\/keyword
```

The string `target` would be in the first group.